# collection.save giving duplicate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The manual says about `.save`:

> When it exists, it replaces it.  When no such document exists, it
>   inserts the document as a new one

So how is it possible to get this error?

```
Error: saveInvoice: WriteError({"code":11000,"index":0,"errmsg":"E11000 duplicate key error collection:
thaihome.invoice index: id dup key: { : 18 }",
"op":{"dueDate":1498885200,"_id":18,"property":"GVV-535","booking":"8KNKU","createDate":1498885200})
```

Here is my code:

```
var invoiceModel = require('../../models/invoiceModel');
invoiceRecord = new invoiceModel(received.invoice)
invoiceRecord.save(function (err, res) {  
    if (err) {
        reject(new Error('saveInvoice: ' + err));
        return;
    }
    show("=====RESOLVE saveInvoice=====")
    resolve();
})
```

I can see mongoose trying to `insert` a new record, but the record is already there.  How do I get `.save` to update when its already there?

Comment: The "document exists" check is based on the `_id` values. Do they match?

Comment: are there mutiple async requests to create that record comes at the same time ?

Comment: @JohnnyHK yes they do match, which makes it very strange

Comment: @thelonglqd no at the moment its just me alone testing on a very fast db server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `Model.update(conditions, doc, [options], [callback])`.

[See the docs here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update).

Set `upsert:true` in the options object.

> upsert (boolean) whether to create the doc if it doesn't match (false)

Comment: OrahKokos that is definitely a good alternative, I just wonder why the .save does not work?

Comment: I think you mixed up mongodb nodejs adapter docs vs mongoose nodejs adapter docs.
Mongo docs: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/insert.html#save
Mongoose docs: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save

Comment: Yeah, that might be it - I just thought .save would work.  The problem with using update is that I now have to enter all the fields manually into the statement correct?

Comment: From the document you just linked to... `If the document contains an _id field, then the save() method is equivalent to an update with the upsert option set to true and the query predicate on the _id field.`   so .save should work!! - I always put an _id into the model

Comment: Orah, so this is my only option?  https://db.tt/R3Duvp4bmb  or can I write `bookingRecord.update(query, upsert...)` and avoid having to write all the fields?

Comment: I tried this `invoiceRecord.update({ _id: invoiceRecord._id },{ upsert: true })` and it does not work - so I really need to write that big long `$set: {}` section with every field, even thou I already have all fields ready in the model?

Comment: Well, I vaguely remember having the same issue while developing apps based on mongoose. After banging my head on the docs (which are hectic), I found this to be the best solution for avoiding duplicate errors. Make sure you just don't have any async related problems and you are good.

Comment: Ahhh!!!  This worked!!  `invoiceRecord.update({ $set: invoiceRecord },{ upsert: true }`  no more writing all the fields one by one heheh.  Thanks Orah :)